# Facebook Open Graph Automatic Thumbnail

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta

I am working on a Jukebox and Facebook Open Graph is frustrating me.

The URL is http://vu2014.host.t-i-m-host.de/jukebox.php?yt=18

If I use the Share Button on the site, it takes the Album Cover.
If I want to post the URL on my Facebook page, it takes the Logo as default.

Here are the META Tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $artist. ' - ' . $title;?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];  ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $cover; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="LOOK.PARTY Jukebox"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="298939876846296"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $artist. ' - ' . $title;?> in der Jukebox von LOOK.PARTY" />
```

Probably it's just a small fail - but maybe someone can help me.
BTW: I searched already in Google and also here in Stackoverflow

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed just a small mistake ;-) The OG image has to be at least 200x200, your album cover is only 170x170.

[Use the Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) the next time to spot such problems before they cause you headache :-)